az command not found when using poetry install
Let's assume this poetry toml file
[tool.poetry]
name = "azurecli"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Install Azure CLI"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
azure-cli = "2.67.0"

poetry.lock file is generated by running poetry lock --no-update and when executed thru dockerfiles to install az cli in alpine based docker image, simple line in Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12.8-alpine3.21
COPY ./pyproject.toml /
COPY ./poetry.lock /
RUN cd / \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python -   \
    && poetry install
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:${PATH}"
RUN  az --version 

Upon running  the docker build command, the log of poetry install does show that azure-cli were installed along with components,  and fails at "az command not found",when checked, there is not even any files found under /root/.local/bin.
When compared to running pip install azure-cli, this does install the binaries and az command is resolved. How do we address using poetry ?
